# whats happen when leaving a CCscene in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

using cocos2d.

i need to know what happen when leaving a scene(replace scene) with the next:

```
shared frame cache (plist and png 's that where spriteSheets )

sprites (the removed?)

actions (they stoped and released?)

bodies (box2d) (i have to destroy them or its auto? )
```

is that happen auto , or i need to do something on the dealloc( ex: removing childs)
thanks .

Answer (score 2):

All caches remain unchanged, it's up to you to remove textures, sprite frames, etc. as needed.

Sprites and all other nodes of the scene are removed automatically. So are actions.

Box2D is a separate library and not integrated in cocos2d's source code. The Box2D source code is merely distributed with cocos2d-iphone. That means you are responsible for cleaning up all Box2D objects and the world. There's nothing automatic there.